# Need help with openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:+91 (number)"]] from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I need to call a number +91 (number),but if i use tel:// url it does not make a call from a iphone app.
How to call a number coming in any format.

Answer (score 1):

The iphone will dial a number using either of the formats listed below.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://15415551234"]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:15415551234"]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                    openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1-541-555-1234"]];
```

[Link for Apple documentation on the tel: url scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)